# Why doesn't hydrazine contain a double bond between two nitrogen atoms?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, pnictogen

I know that the Lewis structure of hydrazine contains $\mathrm{sp^3}$ hybridized nitrogen atom but on analyzing it's structure I realized there are many bond pair and lone pair repulsions. Instead of a single bond between the N atoms they could also have a double bond and a dative bond with h atoms.

When I asked my professor about this he said that the formal charge imparts much more instability. I was not satisfied with the argument. So, can anyone please provide a rigorous explanation of why I am wrong?

Comment: You can't have a dative bond with H atoms. How many electrons will an H atom have, if you would?

Comment: Please edit to show the two Lewis structures you are comparing (the conventional one, and your alternate one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting question! Let's start with the nitrogens in hydrazine being approximately sp2-p hybridized, flat. The p orbitals on each nitrogen would overlap in a double bond configuration - but the "double bond" has four electrons, two from each nitrogen. If you consider a molecular orbital, the bonding AND the antibonding orbitals are filled, so the net bonding is zero. Actually worse than that, because the filled p orbitals on each nitrogen are aligned in the worst way - maximum repulsion.

The clever little nitrogens rehybridize to become pyramidal - perhaps not completely sp3, but not at all planar. This rearrangement hardly affects the N-H bonds, but allows the p orbitals to accept some s-character, which increases one lobe at the expense of the other. And of course, the prominent lobes find a way to point away from each other and reduce electrostatic repulsion of the electrons. You could say that the double bond character is reduced/eliminated, but the bonding loss is more than balanced by reducing the antibonding.

A useful comparison can be made with ethylene: planar, sp2-p, because there are only 2 electrons in the double bond.

Comment: Thank you for such a beautiful explanation!